# Are multiple gears allowed on track cycling bicycles?

Tags: cycling

It seems to me that most track bikes I see have only one gear ratio. For some events I can imagine that having multiple gears would simply be added weight and drag, but on other events, like the short sprints, it seems like a couple of different gears would be of benefit.

Are multiple gears allowed on track cycling bicycles? If so, why are they not used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Track bicycles are not permitted to have multiple gears under UCI regulations.

From their document [*General Organisation of Cycling as a Sport*](http://www.uci.ch/mm/Document/News/Rulesandregulation/16/26/49/PartI-Generalorganisationofcyclingasasport-01.05.2014-ENG_English.pdf), in Chapter III Equipment, part 1.3.025:

> Freewheels, multiple gears and brakes are not permitted for use on the track during competition or training.